# Robocopy Issues

Tags: administrator, robocopy

I try to backup my data with robocopy but having some problems with that:
First thing is, that robocopy copys files that already exists and hasn't been changed.

Also the output looks horrible if it doesn't run under admin rights, but my user has admin rights.

[image]

Comment: are the archive bits set on the files that already exist?

Comment: yes, but if I uncheck the archive bits under the properties, the result is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the copying of files that were already copied you could try adding `/FFT` switch?

If you're copying to a FAT-system (from NTFS) there could be a difference of 2 seconds in date/time saved with the file (which the `/FFT`-switch corrects).

`/FFT :: assume FAT File Times (2-second granularity)`.

---

For the weird output: I read that if you run `RoboCopy` on the `Desktop` (which you are doing) this could be a side effect. (I couldn't find the reason anywhere though)
What happens if you run it from another directory (say `C:\TEMP`)?

You could also try if it does this under another user.

(i couldn't reproduce your output)

Comment: both hdd's have ntfs as filesystem, but even if I copy files from the same partition, it doesn't change.

Comment: To move my batch file to C:\temp helped by the way. Output looks normaly without admin rights.

Comment: Ok, so the output is normal now. But you keep the problem that files (already on the destination) are copied? Can you check manually (by right clicking and properties) of some files to check the date and time are **exactly** the same on source and destination. It's enough to check just 2 or 3 files which keep getting copied this way. And does this effect **all** files or just a few?? BTW You could use the `/L` parameter to see which files are going to be copied without them actually being copied (dry run). Handy for testing purposes (to see which files *would* be copied).

Comment: It could also be the one-hour time difference for certain files. You could overcome that with the `/DST` parameter. `/DST :: compensate for one-hour DST time differences.`

Comment: After I added /timfix it finally works!